# Why is my normal 'if' statement not working on python

Tags: python

I am trying make a maths game but the output says wrong when I answer it correctly. (on python 2.7.2) 
The code:

```
import random
number1 = random.randrange(1, 10)
number2 = random.randrange(1, 10)
print "Whats",number1,"+",number2
answer = raw_input('=')
if answer is (number1 + number2):
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "Wrong!"
```

Comment: you want to use `==` not is

Comment: Use `==` instead of `is`.

Comment: Also, `answer = int(raw_input('='))` will work, because right now it is reading in the users input as a string

Comment: See 'is' vs' '=='. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `==` instead of `is`. `is` is used for checking reference equality. [You can look at this for a better explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/1382766) `raw_input` reads values in as strings by default, so you need to convert it to an integer to be able to check if the input is equal to the answer. Or more simply, use `input` instead.

```
import random
number1 = random.randrange(1, 10)
number2 = random.randrange(1, 10)
print "Whats",number1,"+",number2
answer = input('=')
if answer == (number1 + number2):
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "Wrong!"
```

Comment: I have a lot more experience with coding and this seems like a stupid mistake! Thanks anyway!